# How do I register NGRX provideEffects with Angular 17 standalone?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, angular17

I'm new to Angular 17 and there's really limited docs as to how to use NGRX with new standalone modules or components.

I've installed ngrx effects:

```
npm install @ngrx/effects
```

But now because my application doesn't have an app.modules.ts file I'm struggling to use my effects. Here's my app.config.ts

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideStore } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers, metaReducers } from './reducers';
import { provideEffects } from '@ngrx/effects';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideStore(reducers, { metaReducers }), provideEffects()]
};
```

https://ngrx.io/api/effects/provideEffects

Here's my effect I'm trying to use:

```
@Injectable()
export class PrioritiesEffects {
  getPriorities$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(PrioritiesActions.getPriorities),
      mergeMap(() => {
        return this.prioritiesService.getPriorities().pipe(
          map((priorities) => PrioritiesActions.getPrioritiesSuccess({ priorities })),
          catchError((error) =>
            of(PrioritiesActions.getPrioritiesFailure({ error: error.message }))
          )
        );
      })
    )
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private prioritiesService: PrioritiesService) {}
}
```

In the provideEffects they give an example how to use it with the feature on the router, but I'm unsure how to do that?

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PrioritiesComponent } from './priorities/priorities.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'priority', component: PrioritiesComponent },
];
```

How do I register NGRX provideEffects with Angular 17 standalone?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'priority',
    component: PrioritiesComponent,
    providers: [provideState(YourFeatureState), provideEffects([PrioritiesEffects])],
  },
];
```

Read more here https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/routing-and-lazy-loading-with-standalone-components/

Answer (score 0):

Try creating seperate app.effects module and try adding it to the main.ts file.
Refer the code below :

app.effects.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { AppEffects } from './app.effects'; // Import your effects

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
  ],
})
export class AppEffectsModule { }
```

In you app.effects.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as MyActions from './my-actions'; // Import your actions

@Injectable()
export class AppEffects {
  loadSomething$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(MyActions.loadSomething),
    mergeMap(() => this.myService.getData()
      .pipe(
        map(data => MyActions.loadSomethingSuccess({ data })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      )
    )
  ));

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private myService: MyService // Replace with your service
  ) {}
}
```

In your main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module'; // Import your actual module
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppEffectsModule } from './app.effects.module'; // Import your effects module

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));


AppEffectsModule; // Make sure to import and include it  module
```